# SQL Server vs MySQL, is sargability the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Are the rules of sargability that we use in SQL Server the same for MySQL? If not, how do they differ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, sargability is more a mathematical concept than something defined by DBMS. Certain statements are sargable, certain statements aren't, and the property carries across all DBMS assuming proper implementation. That said, I'd wait for someone that's POSITIVE to make a final call here!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @Kermit, I'm sorry, but this question seems pretty objective to me. Whether or not something is sargable in different RDBMs's is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: Assuming you mean whether a predicate can use an index or not MS-SQL have some advantages over MySQL. In MS-SQL you can add a computed column that can be indexed. In certain circumstances the optimizer can use the indexed computed column even though not mentioned in the predicate.

Comment: @Lennart SQL Server (I don't know what MS-SQL is) can also avoid the issue in other scenarios by default, e.g. `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, column) >= @dt` - [may not always be the best idea, though](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: @Lennart, so you're saying no, they're not necessarily the same rules between systems?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I agree, I used MS-SQL since it was what the OP used.

Comment: @Quandary I didn't down-vote, by the way. But I bet I can tune a SQL Server database to be faster than your PostGreSQL version of the same schema. Also make sure when you consider what "faster" means you measure the whole workload (both read and write), not just one random query. And don't forget to include schema/queries that are likely to go parallel (ouch). I don't think it's possible to make a claim that one RDBMS is faster than another RDBMS - that's like saying my house is better than all houses. Speed of a db and its applications is determined more by the architects than the platform.

Comment: @Quandary Actually, Vertica is much better in this department.

Comment: @Joe, disclaimer MS-SQL (SQL Server) is one of the DBMS I rarely use, but to the best of my knowledge some predicates that are not sargable on MySQL are sargable on SQL Server.

Comment: @Lennart, thanks man!
I'm a bit new to stackoverflow, so I'm a little confused, why have you added this as a comment rather than as a proposed answer?

Comment: @Quandary Also, don't fall into the NoSQL / eventual consistency trap: speed is important, but it's not the *only* important thing, and in a lot of cases it's not even the most important thing.

Comment: @Joe, there is no clear distinction between an small answer and a large comment. In this case I felt that it was more of a remark, than a fully fledged answer.

Comment: Since no one provided an answer I'll make one out of my comments. If someone comes up with a better answer I'll remove it.

Comment: @conduit An optimizer could in theory rearrange or simplify some unsargable expressions to make them sargable though.

Comment: @MartinSmith that is entirely true... I would argue that those were sargable to begin with and improperly written, personally, but that's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean whether a predicate can use an index or not SQL Server has some advantages over MySQL. In SQL Server you can add a computed column that can be indexed. In certain circumstances the optimizer can use the indexed computed column even though not mentioned in the predicate.

AFAIK, there exists predicates that are sargable in SQL Server that are not sargable in MySQL but not the other way around.